Parking Lot Problem and its variations
can someone please explain the problem below in a very simple, step-by-step manner and at the end explain how I need to think for its variations like imagine they are 3 people instead of 2 or that they can park with 2 spaces in between max or both.
Thank you so much in advance and I am incredibly grateful for the help of this community.
Mary and Tom park their cars in an empty parking lot with n>=2 consecutive parking spaces (i.e, n spaces in a row, where only one car fits in each space). Mary and Tom pick parking spaces at random; of course, they must each choose a different space. (All pairs of distinct parking spaces are equally likely.) What is the probability that there is at most one empty parking space between them?
Your answer should be a function of n.

Hello William and welcome on CrossValidated. Is it a homework question? If it is, it is OK, but you should explain what you have tried to solve the problem, and where you are stuck exactly. Read this page for more information.

Start with simpler versions: in how many ways can M and T park next to each other?  In how many ways can M and T park exactly one space apart?

The simple version is relatively straightforward as you can easily count all the cases where Mary and Tom are parked next to each other.

In the more general case, you can consider k cars taking up h spaces and compute the probability that they overlap. For large numbers you may approximate it and it becomes similar to the birthday problem.

Hi - it is a homework question that I could solve for two people only with one space in between. However, I have no clue how to approach it for different variations in terms of number of people and allowed spaces in between. I asked for someone to solve it and then to change the number of people and/or spaces in between to see the logic of their solution.

And what we're suggesting is that you are likely to see the logic of a solution when you attempt the simpler versions of the problem.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info for why we are suggesting that.

If this is a homework question, then how is it phrased exactly? The variations "how I need to think for its variations like imagine they are 3 people instead of 2 or that they can park with 2 spaces in between max or both." complicate the problem a lot and make the potential answers diverse in many different ways. What is the exact point of the question if this is a homework question? Or is the homework question just the simple question and you wonder about the complications if the homework question gets more complicated?
